# Update list text after eventListener in vue

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, web

I have this problem with Vue. What I want is if I click on hello it should change the count from `6` to `7`. Need help on this thing.

```
<script>
   export default {
   data: function() {
         list = 5
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.count) 
    this.count = 5
    this.list = 6
  },  
  methods: {
    // want to change
    say() {
      this.list = 7      
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  Count is: {{ count }}
  count us: {{ list }}
  <button @click="say()">
    hello
  </button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code doesn't work as expected is because `this` inside the data function is not the component instance, it's the component context.

If you want to create a reactive property called `list` on the instance, you have to place a `list` property with a value other than `undefined` on the object returned by the data function.

Your example, fixed:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    count: 1,
    list: 5
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.count);
    this.count = 5;
    this.list = 6;
  },
  methods: {
    say() {
      this.list = 7
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<div id="app">
  Count is: {{ count }}<br>
  List is: {{ list }}<br>
  <button @click="say">
    hello
  </button>
</div>
```

Now, if you change `this.list` to anything else in any method or component hook, the template will update accordingly.

Obviously, the data function doesn't have to be an arrow function.

```
data: function() {
  return {
    count: 1,
    list: 5 
  }
}
```

... works, too. Another note is that the data can also be an object. In your case

```
data: {
  count: 1,
  list: 5
}
```

...would work. However, this syntax is [not recommended](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html?redirect=true#data-Must-Be-a-Function), as multiple instances of the same component would be sharing the same reactive data which is, in most cases, not the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax was wrong, take a look at following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      list: [1,2,3,4],
    }
  }, 
  methods:{
    say(){
      this.list.push(this.list.length + 1)   
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
  <button @click="say">
    hello
  </button>
</div>
```